# Can Win32 message loops survive being ported to native linux?

Tags: c++, linux, portability

I would like to port a large Win32 DLL to native linux in C++.  I don't think I can use Wine for a DLL like mine, because users of the DLL would then also have to be in Wine, and then they would all whine...  As a Windows C++ programmer, I don't (yet) have any familiarity with the GUI front-end services in linux, but if it logically runs on anything like win32 message loops, fonts, bitmaps, invalidation regions, getmessage( ) calls and so forth, it should be a fairly straight forward remapping of my existing code.

So what am I looking at here, a remap or a rewrite? The path for such things must be well worn by now.

Comment: The path is Wine, and other similar emulators.  They're already doing what you are attempting.

Comment: Ok, so my DLL sits on top of Wine, that sits on top of linux.  User code sees my api/DLL, and doesn't necessarily care what it sits on. I like it--no remap, no rewrite, just new scripts and rebuild.  Thank you.

Comment: Hopefully it's that simple. :)

Answer (score 2):

Why not consider using Qt or some cross-platform library to solve this question?

Does your solution have GUI related core or just processing functions? Pure C/C++ cross-platform coding would be enough in this case.

Comment: A C++ cross-platform framework that provides consistent front-ends, file handling and networking, while giving my multithreaded concurrency services free reign, would be a much better solution than Wine. I am looking into Qt now, can you name any others that I should also consider?

Comment: There is [wxWidgets](http://www.wxwidgets.org/) also [GTK+](http://www.gtk.org/) and [SDL](http://www.libsdl.org/). These I know that are widely used.  

You may also take a look on this [Stack Overflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6559099/alternatives-to-qt) to know about other alternatives to QT